# what is the default filter chain configured for spring security?

Tags: java, spring-security

Any idea what is the default filter chain configured for spring security wit spring security namespace 
`xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security".` I did not spot default configuration
on net.

Referenced link was [security-filter-chain](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html)

Answer (score 4):

Here is default Security Chain Filter where `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` is called first

1)SecurityContextPersistenceFilter

2)LogoutFilter

3)UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter

4)DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter

5)BasicAuthenticationFilter

6)RequestCacheAwareFilter

7)SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter

8)AnonymousAuthenticationFilter

9)SessionManagementFilter

10)ExceptionTranslationFilter

11)FilterSecurityInterceptor

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you mean by "the default filter chain", but you can easily see the configured filters for a particular configuration by looking at the stack in the debug log (for example, when logging in, it will print a stack when access is denied initially).

You can also add the [`<debug>` element](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-namespace) to an XML configuration and it will print out the filters which will be invoked.